# Firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

I'm a newbie with firebase and want to set up a simple login module for a website. I set up a page with a form and two fields:
1. Mailaddress
2. Password
When the login is authenticated I like to direct to a another page.

I have two questions:

Question 1.: When I look in my source code I see the error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined"

[image]

I checked the url in my dashboard of Firebase and it is correct. Is there something I am doing wrong.

Quesion 2.: I have looked for a login exmple with firebase, but I only could find an example build with the old deprecated version of Firebase (which I am trying to use in my example).

Hope somebody can give me some leads or tips. Would be very gratefull.

Thnks!
Kenneth

Comment: You shouldn't try to learn Firebase using deprecated versions. Your issue will probably be solved by following the guides [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) (especially *Installation & Setup* and *User Authentication* further down).

Comment: Thanks Marein for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

*As Marein remarked in his comment, don't waste your time trying to learn about a platform on an older version. It's simply not worth the hassle and it'll be almost drastically reduce our ability to help you.*

That said:

1. You're only including the simple-login script, which used to be separate from Firebase's regular JavaScript SDK. So the error message signals that you also have to include the regular SDK. For today's Firebase, if you go to the [front page of Firebase's documentation for the JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/), you'll find that the JavaScript SDK can be found at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js. This latest SDK includes both the core Firebase functionality *and* the login functionality. So if you just replace your current included script with this one, you'll be good to go
2. Now that you've included the current version, you can find example of authentication on this page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html